# How to express cURL snippet as full HTTP request with Header and Body

Tags: javascript, http, curl

I read and re-read answers to below Stack question and I'm still not getting it.

Can someone help me figure out (er, with an example), how to express a working cURL snippet as a full HTTP request?

[Stack question](https://superuser.com/questions/361504/how-to-send-post-with-body-data-headers-andhttp-params-over-the-curl-command)

AND:   Here is the cURL snippet.

curl -s --insecure https://api.yahoo.com/nvp -d "USER=joe@mymail.com&PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&METHOD=SendNow&VERSION=103&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&YOURCODE=ABC&EMAILSUBJECT= You have a new email&L_EMAIL0=sam@hismail.com&L_SMT0=103&L_NOTE0= Have a blast.&L_UNIQUEID0=TrackNum0001"

and I need to express it as:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.example.com/create_post',
body: {
  title: 'Vote for Pedro',
  body: 'If you vote for Pedro, your wildest dreams will come true'
},
success: function(httpResponse) {
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
}
});
```

Comment: Please include code that you've tried in the question and describe the specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.yahoo.com/nvp',
    body: {
        USER: 'joe@mymail.com',
        PWD: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        SIGNATURE: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' // etcc..
    },
    success: function (httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  Do you think I need a "Header"?

Comment: You are not sending any headers with the Curl request, so I don't see why should here.

Comment: OK.  working on testing it now.  Thanks.  Question:  the URL has a ' -d" at the end.  Should I just put that into the Post URL?

Comment: the "-d" should not be in the url. "-d" is a flag, used to specify a POST body to Curl. see - http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d